Modulus inequalities and checking solutions
I have a question: x is an element of R : |x-4| > 3.
I used the method where I square both sides to get a quadratic, let = 0, factorise and solve. I got two answers for x, (typo: -4 and 7.) values for x found were actually 1 and 7.
When I check each answer in the original question I get |3| > 3, which can't be the case.
I'm wondering am I letting the sum = 0 in the wrong place? Should this be done at the very start so that when I check the answers I'm getting |3|=3? Or is there something else I'm missing here?

You solved for $|x-4| = 3$ (an equality) so of course checking the solutions won't give the inequality.  Solving the EQuality shows you where the values break and you will get $|x-4|=3$ when $x = 1, x=7$.  You need to check the intervals between.  If $x < 1$ then $x-4 < -3$ and $|x-4| >3$.  If $1< x < 7$ then $-3 < x-4 < 3$ and $|x-4| < 3$ and if $x > 7$ then $x-4 > 3$ and $|x-4| > 3$.  So the solutions are $x < 1$ or $x > 7$.

By the way was your saying you got "two answers for x, -4 and 7" a typo?  If $|x-4| =3\implies x^2-8x + 16 = 9 \implies x^2-8x+7 =(x-1)(x-7)=0\implies x=1, 7$.

When you set things EQUAL to zero you are ignoring the inequality exactly and you are solving for when $|x-4| > 3$ is NOT true and instead are solving for $|x-4|=3$.
This is a valid method however to find the "breaks" where the inequality ceases to be true and that gives you the interals where they are true.
To do it this way we do $|x-4| = 3$
$(|x-4|)^2 = 3^2$
$x^2 -8x +16 = 9$
$x^2 - 8x + 7 = 0$
$(x-1)(x-7) = 0$
$x = 1$ or $7$  (I assume the $-4$ was a typo?)
So we know the "break" points are $1$ and $7$ and we test between those point.
If $x < 1$ or $1 < x < 7$ or $x > 7$.  Testing those we get: If $x < 1$ then $|x-4| > 3$.  If $1< x < 7$ then $|x-4| < 3$ and if $x > 7$ then $|x-4| > 7$ so the solution is $x< 1$ or $x > 7$.
....
BUT....
That's a very informal way of doing it.  If we want to be more formal we'd do
$0 < 3 < |x-4|$
$0 < 3^2 < |x-4|^2$
$9 < x^2-8x +16$
$x^2 - 8x+7 > 0$
$(x-1)(x-7) > 0$
so ....
Either both $x-1$ and $x-7$ are both greater than $0$ and so $x-7>0$ so $x > 7$ (and $x-1 > 0$ so $x>1$ so $x > \max (1,7) = 7$) and the solution is $x > 7$.
OR both $x -1$ and $x-7$ are both less than $0$ so $x-1 < 0$ and $x < 1$.  (and $x-7 > 0$ so $x < 7$ so $x < \min (1,7) =1$) and the solution is $x < 1$.
....
But given all that I find it better not to square and add more information that might lead to extraneous results.
It'd be, in my opinion, clearer to do
$|x-4| > 3$  In which case either $(x-4) \ge 0$ and $|x-4| = x-4 > 3$ so $x > 7$
or $(x-4) < 0$ and $-(x-4) = -x +4 > 3$ so $-x > -1$ or $x < 1$.
